# SoapUI enable list of test steps (Groovy)

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have some SoapUI test cases, where I need to enable specific test steps.
I decided to wrote a simple Groovy script which enables required test steps.

At first I disable all test steps in the test case:

```
//Get the names of all test steps
def oNameList = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepList().name
for(iNameCounter in (0..oNameList.size-1))
{  
testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName(oNameList[iNameCounter]).setDisabled(true)
}
```

Then I have list with test steps to enable:

```
def list = ['Login', 'Get Messages', 'Logout']

for (i = 0; i <list.size; i++) {
testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName(list[i]).setDisabled(false)
}
```

It works If 'list' elements exist as test steps in that test case. But not If one of them is missing. **Is it possible to make it skip missing test steps?** I need to make this groovy work on every test case (in 'list' there will be all preferred test steps from every test case in test suite).

**For example:**

1. I have Test case with these test steps: *'Login', 'See bill history', 'Logout'.*
2. I will run this groovy script which disable  all test steps.
3. Then it starts to enable test steps specified in the *'list'*.
4. But it fails because in that test case there doesn't exist test step *'Get messages'*.
5. I want to make it to skip enabling test steps from *'list'* which doesn't exist in the actual test case.
6. Output on this test case should be - **enabled:** *'Login', 'Logout'*; **disabled:** *'See bill history'*

Comment: HI, you can condition your workflow : TC = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName, then if(TC != null) TC.setDisable(false)

Comment: @ A. Joly, it works now, thank you